# Debugging in rails Console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I have this script that i would like to test within the rails console

```
Gem.find_files("models/*.rb").each do |f| 
  filename = File.basename(f, '.*')
  class_name_symbol = filename.classify.to_sym
  autoload class_name_symbol, "models/#{filename}"
end
```

what i would like to do is print out the results in the console but can only get as far as outputting the array using

```
 Gem.find_files("models/*.rb")
```

which returns this

```
["/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/portfolio_sector.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/post.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/image.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/message.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/sector.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/portfolio.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/category.rb"]
```

tips appreciated

After using answer the output is

```
models/portfolio_sector
models/post
models/message
models/sector
models/portfolio
models/category
=> ["/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/portfolio_sector.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/post.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/image.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/message.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/sector.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/portfolio.rb", "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-8360dfc861ad/lib/models/category.rb"]
```

not sure why the array is at the end?

**Edit :**

The script is supposed to take each item in the array and autoload the file contained in models/#{filename}. I would like to print out all the model/#{filename} paths in the console to ensure they are correct –

Comment: Just insert a `puts` in correct place. See my answer.

Comment: because it returns an enumerator from the `#each` methods, so you get the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Gem.find_files("models/*.rb").each do |f| 
  filename = File.basename(f, '.*')

  # So, instead of passing this filename to autoload, you print it. Or do both.
  puts "models/#{filename}"

  # class_name_symbol = filename.classify.to_sym
  # autoload class_name_symbol, "models/#{filename}"
end && nil # suppress return value from `each`
```

Comment: Debug printing is very useful technique. :)

Comment: yes it seems that way, im going to post the output in my question, why does the array appear at the end?

Comment: @Richlewis: because it's the return value of `each`. See updated answer.

Comment: so when im autoloading im loading the paths models/portfolio for example and not the paths in the array? I only ask as im loading these paths within a gem and it is not loading any of my model classes